# Config file seems not working in verdaccio

Tags: docker, npm, verdaccio

I have configured `verdaccio` on a centos server and followed the tuto in the documentation. I used a docker container and my repository tree looks like this :

```
/root/verdacio/
         |_____ conf/
         |       |___config.yaml 
         |_____ logo
         |      |____mylogo.ico
         |      |____mylogo.png
         |_____ plugins
         |_____ storage
```

My `config.yaml` file look like this :

```
storage: /root/verdaccio/storage
plugins: /root/verdaccio/plugins
web:
  enable: true
  title: "MyStartUp"
  logo: /root/verdaccio/logo/mylogo.png
  gravatar: true
  scope: "@mystartup"
  sort_packages: asc | desc
  darkmode: true
  favicon: /root/verdaccio/logo/mylogo.ico
auth:
  htpasswd:
    file: ./htpasswd
uplinks:
  npmjs:
    url: https://registry.npmjs.org/
packages:
  '@mystartup/':
    access: $authenticated
    publish: $authenticated
  '@*/*':
    access: $authenticated
    publish: $authenticated
    unpublish: $authenticated
    proxy: npmjs
  '**':
    access: $authenticated
    publish: $authenticated
    unpublish: $authenticated
    proxy: npmjs
middlewares:
  audit:
    enabled: true
max_body_size: 100mb
logs:
  - {type: stdout, format: pretty, level: http}
```

My questions are:
Why do I find my packages (when I publish one) in `/var/lib/docker/volumes/someID/_data/data` ? I had a hard time finding them.
Why the logo doesn't work and I still have verdaccio's logo in the UI, the title remains verdaccio and even though I'm not authenticated, when I go to the web ui, I still can download the packages (not yet tested via the terminal) ?

I thought it could be a problem due to the location of the conf file (since I saw in one of the youtube video that the guy had something like `~/verdaccio/conf/verdaccio/config.yaml` and I did the same, restart the docker container but my problem remained.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've resolved my problem in a dirty way but it works anyway. I went to the root directory of my linux server and typed `find -type f -name "config.yaml"` and therefore I've found the default config file that verdaccio were using, I did some modifications and everything were working fine except the logo that I can't change since according to what I understand, I can't use a path for it but an http link.

Comment: Nice neat idea. Did you find a way to tell verdaccio to use your config file then?

Comment: No, I did not unfortunately.